# Pattern matching Scala (key, Tuple2) values in reduceByKey() for Apache Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I have an RDD containing `(stockName, stockValue)` tuples. Many of the stocks are repeated and have differing values.

e.g. `("ARM", 200.6)` `("GOOG", 4000.4)` `("ARM", 3998.23)` `("ARM", 4002.45)` etc.

The idea is to collect all like stocks and calculate their averages.

In the code below the `map` transforms each stock into `(key, (total, 1))`

e.g. `("ARM", (200.6, 1))`

The `reduceByKey` aggregates all stocks with the same name and independently sums their values and counts. Making it's easy to calculate the average for each stock (code not shown).

`val partial = stocks.map{ case(stock: String, value: Double) => (stock, (value, 1)) }
                     .reduceByKey( (x, y) => (x._1 + y._1, x._2 + y._2) )`

In the `map` I've been able to use pattern matching to clearly express the transformation. I'd like to be able to do the same thing with the function argument passed to `reduceByKey` in order to make it more readable.

So far I've not been able to improve on `(x, y) => (x._1 + y._1, x._2 + y._2)`.

Any suggestions?

Comment: `stocks.groupBy(_._1).mapValues(_.foldLeft((0.0, 0))((total, next) => (total._1 + next._2, total._2 + 1))) // Map(ARM -> (8201.279999999999,3), GOOG -> (4000.4,1))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can nest patterns to deconstruct `(x, y)` into `((x1, x2), (y1, y2))`

```
val partial = stocks.map {
  case (stock, value) => stock -> (value, 1)
}.reduceByKey {
  case ((value1, count1), (value2, count2)) => (value1 + value2, count1 + count2)
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I had tried that but it turns out I had an unrelated problem. I was actually doing a `.reduceByKeyAndWindow` (the code is part of a Spark Streaming application) and was passing an additional `Seconds(20)` parameter, the code looked like:  `.reduceByKeyAndWindow( (x, y) => (x._1 + y._1, x._2 + y._2), Seconds(20) )`. To use the pattern matched version I needed to insert some extra `{}`, the code now looks like: `reduceByKeyAndWindow( {case((value1, count1), (value2, count2)) => (value1 + value2, count1 + count2)}, Seconds(20) )`. This works! I'm slowly transitioning from Java to Scala!